# VPS: switched PHP version but still can't install symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, vps

I'm trying to install symfony4 on my VPS, and I have switched to PHP7 but when I run `composer install` I get this error:

```
symfony/flex v1.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.38) does not satisfy that requirement
```

Although when I run `php -v` I get this:

```
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.32 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 21:21:05) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

I did restarted Apache but still the same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have installed more versions on your system and `composer` use the older version. You should check some locations.

```
#/bin/php -v
```

i think some of your locations have the old version in it. And you have another PATH location in your path variable, where you have the newer version installed. What you can try is to run composer directly with your php version.

```
#/your/path/to/7/php composer update
```

then you run that composer phar file with the php version you define.

Comment: you're right I have 3 versions of php installed, how can I make php7 the one in use ?

Comment: Hmm you can try `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2` normally when you install PHP7 then the installer should set the newest version but in your case that isn't done.

Comment: thanks, it's working fine now after `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/local/bin/ea-php70` :)